# update values in a string to another table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called prods

```
create table prods (product text,qty int)
```

and in another table I've a column with following data

```
'incoming product-Acid Freyin|quantity-100'
'incoming product-Acid OTUI|quantity-110'
```

So, My question is how to insert values to `prods` with product and qty from above data i.e

```
Acid Freyin 100
Acid OTUI   110
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using PostgreSQL's `split_part()` function

```
insert into prods (product,qty)  
select split_part(split_part(val,'|',1),'-',2) product
      ,split_part(split_part(val,'|',2),'-',2)::int qty 
from ttss
```